# Cannot Authenticate user in Cake PHP 4.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have setup latest cake ph setup and when I try to login user it gives me this error

**Argument 1 passed to Cake\Http\Session::_overwrite() must be of the type array, null given**

My code is

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if ($user) {
    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
}
```

When I check $user it gives me the identified user but later it gives me above error.

Comment: Pleas read and follow documentation https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html

Comment: @Salines Thank you but I have already referred ti this,but couldn't find solution on it

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message, and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`)! In your specific case you should inspect all errors (clear the logs, run your code, check the logs), as your problem means that the `$_SESSION` superglobal is `null`, meaning the session possibly wasn't started correctly, which could be due to additional errors.

Answer (score -1):

Remove array type in Session.php in  _overwrite function in vendor. as shown below code.
It's work for me.
/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http

```
protected function _overwrite( &$old, array $new): void{
 if (!empty($old)) {
  foreach ($old as $key => $var) {
   if (!isset($new[$key])) { 
    unset($old[$key]);
   }
  }
 }
 foreach ($new as $key => $var) {
   
   $old[$key] = $var;


 }

}
```